# How to insert attribute selector for Hgroup subsection

Tags: css

I have looked up for attribute selector on several website but I still don't get it. If I am having this part of the code,

```
<hgroup>
    <h2>HTML5 History</h2>
</hgroup>
```

How am I supposed to use the attribute selector so that my css code will only apply it to h2 and not the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
hgroup.change h2{
  color:red;
}
hgroup#change h2{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<hgroup class="change">
    <h2>HTML5 History</h2>
    <p>HTML5 History</p>
    <span>HTML5 History</span>
</hgroup>
<hgroup id="change">
    <h2>HTML5 History</h2>
    <p>HTML5 History</p>
    <span>HTML5 History</span>
</hgroup>
<hgroup>
    <h2>HTML5 History</h2>
    <p>HTML5 History</p>
    <span>HTML5 History</span>
</hgroup>
```

Comment: What if I have numerous hgroup, is it possible to select which hgroup I want?

Comment: @Luke Just add class or id to it. I edited my answer.. Try to look at it..